# Problems with JavaScript (probably Math.floor(Math.random() or do-while)

Tags: javascript, html, math, do-while

The code below isn't working: I previewed it with Brackets, and it only shows the titles of the text ("JavaScript Math" and 
"Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) arpoo luvun 1-10 väliltä"). What is wrong here? My browser supports JavaScript, so that isn't the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h2>JavaScript Math</h2>
<p>Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) arpoo luvun 1-10 väliltä</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var oikealuku=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oikealuku;
var luku=0, i=0;
do
{
    luku=prompt ("Arvaa luku");
     if (i==3)
}
{
alert("Liian monta yritystä");
    break;
}
if(luku == oikealuku)
    alert ("Oikein. Oikea luku oli" +oikealuku);
    exit ();
{
if(luku < oikealuku)
{
alert ("Väärä arvaus! Luku on suurempi kuin" +oikealuku);
}
if (luku > oikealuku)
alert ("Väärä vastaus! Luku on pienempi kuin" +oikealuku);
i++;
}
{
while (luku!=oikealuku)`
alert ("Arvottu luku oli" +oikealuku);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax for a do-while is `do { CODE } while(CONDITION)`

Comment: In the future, check your browser's console for errors.

Comment: An HTML tag just contains text, it doesn't execute any Javascript. You'll probably want to give it an `id` and use `document.getElementById()` in your script, and alter its value there.

Comment: Anyway, the syntax is all over the place. You have an `if` by itself inside a `do...while`-without `while`, a `break` that breaks nothing, an `exit()` function that doesn't exist. I'd suggest you go back to square one in whatever tutorial/book you're using.

Comment: Looks like you haven't checked that your code is actually running properly

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with the syntax of your JavaScript code – mostly mismatched/extraneous brackets and a stray backtick character on the `while` line.

Fixing those – and reindenting your code for readability – gets you this. Hope this helps.

```
var oikealuku = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oikealuku;
var luku = 0,
  i = 0;
do {
  luku = prompt("Arvaa luku");
  if (i == 3) {
    alert("Liian monta yritystä");
    break;
  }
  if (luku == oikealuku) {
    alert("Oikein. Oikea luku oli" + oikealuku);
    break;
  } else if (luku < oikealuku) {
    alert("Väärä arvaus! Luku on suurempi kuin" + oikealuku);
  } else if (luku > oikealuku) {
    alert("Väärä vastaus! Luku on pienempi kuin" + oikealuku);
  }
  i++;
} while (luku != oikealuku);
alert("Arvottu luku oli" + oikealuku);
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the code for you. There were some syntax errors:

`do {CODE TO DO WHILE} while (CONDITION)`

`alert () after if () and before`

Check the code now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>
<body>
    <h2>JavaScript Math</h2>
    <p>Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1) arpoo luvun 1-10 väliltä</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    var oikealuku=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = oikealuku;
    var luku=0, i=0;
    do {
        luku = prompt("Arvaa luku");
        if (i == 3) {
            alert("Liian monta yritystä");
            break;
        }
        if (luku == oikealuku) {
            alert("Oikein. Oikea luku oli" + oikealuku);
            if (luku < oikealuku) {
                alert("Väärä arvaus! Luku on suurempi kuin" + oikealuku);
            }
            if (luku > oikealuku) {
                alert("Väärä vastaus! Luku on pienempi kuin" + oikealuku);
            }
            i++;
        }
    } while (luku != oikealuku){
        alert ("Arvottu luku oli" +oikealuku);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the part about the `<p>` tag containing the literal string `Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)`

Comment: More important, you have two bodies for your `do...while`: one after the `do`, another one after the `while`.